# How can I use import in background.js in my firefox and chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm using vanilla javascript and am doing this at the top of `background.js` for firefox:

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["scripts/background.js"]
  },
```

and chrome:

```
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "scripts/service-worker.js"
  },
```

In both `service-worker.js` and `background.js` I need to use `import { thing } from './scripts/utils.js'`

How can I do this? I get an error in firefox that says import can only be used at the top of a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In ManifestV2 Firefox/Chrome specify `page` + load the script file explicitly as a module:

  manifest.json:

  ```json
    "background": {
      "page": "bg.html"
    },
  ```

  bg.html:

  ```html
  <script src="scripts/background.js" type="module"></script>
  ```
- In ManifestV3 Chrome specify `type`:

  manifest.json:

  ```json
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "scripts/service-worker.js",
      "type": "module"
    },
  ```

Comment: should I remove the `background.js` from the firefox manifest?

Comment: Yes, the code in the answer shows the entire thing, not the delta.